# Check date range is not already booked in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working in an online bike booking system where the customer can book a bike for a particular date-time range. If another customer books the same bike for a specified date-time range, I have to check whether the bike is already booked or not. My database table `reservations` looks like this:

```
id     bike_id      start_date             end_date
 1        1      2019-05-04 14:30      2019-05-04 15:30
 1        1      2019-05-04 16:30      2019-05-04 18:30
```

The query:

```
Reservations::where('bike_id', $yacht)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
        $query->where(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
            $query->where('start_date', '<', $startTime)
                ->where('end_date', '>', $startTime);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
            $query->where('start_date', '>', $endTime)
                ->where('end_date', '<', $endTime);
        });
    })
    ->count();
```

Unfortunately, the code does not seem to work. It does not check the condition properly. How to do the desired check properly using the given inputs?

Comment: Your query lacks an `exists()`, `count()` or `get()` at the end. Did you just forget copying it into the question or is there really none?

Comment: Also does your table with example data not match the column names used in the query: can you clarify those?

Answer (score 4):

Namoshek's answer, based on your code, is correct. Personally, I find all the nested functions hard to read. They're not avoidable in a query like this, but they can be reduced:

```php
$bike = Bike::findOrFail($yacht);
$conflict = $bike->reservations()
    ->whereBetween('start_date', [$startTime, $endTime])
    ->orWhereBetween('end_date' [$startTime, $endTime])
    ->orWhere(fn ($q) => $q->where('start_date', '<', $startTime)->where('end_date', '>', $endTime))
    ->exists();
if ($conflict) {
    abort(409);
}
// continue saving the reservation
```

I'm assuming that you have correctly set up relations between your `Bike` and `Reservation` models, so can take advantage of them to make the code more readable still. (And you'll probably be finding that bike object later in the code anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to check is whether the start date-time or the end date-time of the new booking lies within any existing record. In other words, there is two cases, as you already identified correctly, where one deals with the start time of the new booking and one with the end time. If any (or both) of them lie within an existing booking, the check failed.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$similarBookingExists = Reservations::query()
    ->where('bike_id', $yacht)
    ->where(function (Builder $query) use ($startTime, $endTime) {
        $query->where(function (Builder $query) use ($startTime) {
            $query->where('start_date', '<=', $startTime)
                ->where('end_date', '>=', $startTime);
        })
        ->orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($endTime) {
            $query->where('start_date', '<=', $endTime)
                ->where('end_date', '>=', $endTime);
        });
    })
    ->exists();
```

In short, the only mistake you made were the comparison operators `<` and `>` of the second case for `$endTime`.

Comment: Also you should write `>=` and `<=` insetad of `>` and `<`

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze You are right, thank you for pointing it out. It should be noted though that, depending on the kind of booking times you can select, it should be `>=` but `<` to allow the end of a previous booking to be the beginning of a new booking. In other words, the end may be `2020-03-04 12:00:00.000` if at the same time a new booking begins and it does not need to be `2020-03-04 11:59:59.999` (which adds precision issues).

Comment: Then he can specify intervals but query will get very complex. But without equality operators I can't book from `2019-05-04 15:30` to `2019-05-04 16:30` but it's free