# Check if given date is available from multiple table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, relationship

I am working on online reservation system where customer will search for room available with time and number of people. My database table looks like this:

Table: **Property**

| id | property_name | property_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc property | AB-123 |
| 2 | def property | DF-343 |

*property_number* is unique field

Table: **Rooms**

| id | Room Name | Capacity | property_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Room one | 150 | AB-123 |
| 1 | Room two | 500 | AB-123 |
| 2 | Room one | 500 | DF-343 |

*property_number* is foreign key from table *property*

Table: **Booking**

| id | property_number | room_id | book_status | book_start | book_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AB-123 | 1 | active | 2021-06-06 10:00:00 | 2021-06-06 18:00:00 |

*property_number* is foreign key from table *property*

*room_d* is foreign key from table *Room*

*book_status* : completed, pending, running, cancelled. If booking status is completed or cancelled than user should be able to book.

> User Search Field

- Reservation Date
- Reservation Start Time
- Reservation End Time
- Total no of People
- User Submits Specific Property Number

[Solution Tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525254/check-date-range-is-not-already-booked-in-laravel-6)

```
$property = Property:::where('status','active')->where('property_number',$property_number)->firstOrFail();
$bookings = $property->bookings()
                        ->whereBetween('event_date_start',[$event_start,$event_end])
                        ->orWhereBetween('event_date_end',[$event_start,$event_end])
                        ->orWhere( function ( $query ) use ($event_start,$event_end) {
                            $query->where('event_date_start' , '<', $event_start)->where('event_date_end','>',$event_end);
                        })
                        ->get();
```

```
Model Structure
Table: **Property**
Class Property extends Model {
  public function bookings(){
    return $this->hasMany(Bookings::class,'property_number','property_number');
  }
  public function rooms(){
    return $this->hasMany(Rooms::class,'property_number','property_number');
  }
}
Table: **Rooms**
Class Rooms extends Model {
 public function property(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Property::class,'property_number','property_number');
 }

 public function bookings(){
   return $this->hasMany(Bookings::class,'room_id');
 }
}

Table: **Bookings**
Class Bookings extends Model {
}
```

This way it checks only property not every room associated with the property.

- How to check if any room is available for booking for provided property.*

Comment: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.